# Как выяснить позицию курсора в textarea при событии dragover?

Tags: javascript, html

При выделении текста в textarea позицию курсора и выделения можно получить прочитав свойства textarea.selectionStart, textarea.selectionEnd и textarea.selectionDirection (рис. 1).

Далее, если начинать перетаскивать выделенный текст то помимо выделения отображается еще дополнительный курсор, указывающий на позицию, куда будет перенесен выделенный фрагмент при завершении переноса (рис. 2).

Вот позицию этого дополнительного курсора хотелось бы получить из события dragover.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]